# select top 5 rows for type1 else type2 in DB2

Tags: select, db2

I want to select top 5 rows where area is 'newyork' and select any records if no records available or select other 2 if only 3 records found for area 'newyork' then select remaining records accordingly. Example select * from tablename where area = 'newyork' fetch top 5 rows only  [If only 3 reocords exists then select remaining 2 rows with other available area]. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want the 'newyork' to be sorted first, here's one way.

```
select
  case when area = 'newyork' then 0 else 1 end as nyFlag
  <whatever else>
from mytable
order by 1, <....>
fetch first 5 rows only
```